# How to know when you change the dimensions of an element in the DOM

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("scroll", function () {
 console.log("scroll Event...");
});
function WrapText() {
 document.getElementById("container").classList.add("WrapText");
}
```

```css
div {
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background-color:yellow;
 overflow: auto;
}
div.WrapText{
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<button onClick="WrapText()">Wrap Text</button>
```

When I do `Scroll` I detect it through the event **onScroll** and display a message in console.

Now, when I press the `Wrap Text` button, I scale the window and adjust it to the text.

**The problem:**
I do not know how to detect this last event through `addEventListener()`, that is, how to know when I re-dimension an element in the **DOM**?

**NOTE:**
It is important that the solution be through an event handler appended to `<div id ="container">` as we do with the event **onScroll** and not for the event **onClick** applied to the element `<Button>`.

Comment: You're already doing it? You know when someone clicked, and that's what you should use. Anything else is probably just trying to solve an X/Y problem.

Comment: Check mutation observers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Your problem isn't clear. If you want to resize the #container div when it's scrolled, call `WrapText()` in that event handler.

Comment: @AndrewR - I want to know how to use `addEventListener()` in case of resizing a div

Answer (score 1):

If you work with jQuery can use:

```
$('#container').bind('height-changed',function(){...});
$('#container').css({height:'100%'});
$('#container').trigger('height-changed');
```

To capture more events when the style of DOM object changes, try with:

```
var event = new $.Event('style');
```

or

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(<<function>>)
```